# Position absolute for Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am a newbie for Flutter who comes from Web Development side. Just for fun and practice for Flutter layout, I wanted to make a "drum kit" application. But the problem is, I can not set Drum Kit parts as it should be.

You know in web development, there is position absolute option for the elements on the webpage. Is there anything like that for Flutter?

I'd appreciate any answers. Thanks. :)

Let me show what I expected : [Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sOpN.png)

This is what I got as a result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wkkt.jpg)

Comment: Kindly paste your code. Avoid posting images as their content cannot be indexed

Answer (score 5):

The `Stack` widget and `Positioned` widget helps you achieve this:

According to the official documentation:

> A `Stack` is a widget that positions its children relative to the edges of its box.
> This class is useful if you want to overlap several children in a simple way, for example having some text and an image, overlaid with a gradient and a button attached to the bottom.

> A `Positioned` is a widget that controls where a child of a Stack is positioned.A Positioned widget must be a descendant of a Stack.

Read more about the `Stack` widget here: [Stack Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Read more about the `Positioned` widget here: [Positioned Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)

**Taking your example, you will need to create a `Stack` widget and the `children` property of the `Stack` widget should be your `drum parts` wrapped in a `Positioned` widget. The `Positioned` widget should only be used in the `Stack` widget.**

Answer (score 3):

```
     Stack(
children: <Widget>[
  Positioned(
    top: 100,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    child: Text("Search",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff757575),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              fontFamily: "Roboto",
              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
              fontSize: 56.0),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center),
  ),
 ]
 )
```

you can try this You can fix position in the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stack class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html), which will have a [Positioned class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)

**How does it help**

- Stack helps you have `relative-layout`
- Positioned helps you adjust the item like `absolute` in web